# RuntimeError: Failed to init API, possibly an invalid tessdata path: C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\/tessdata/

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, language-detection

I am using windows 10 and tesserocr version is 2.4.
Want to detect text from an image and then the language of that text.

While running this piece of code:

```
from tesserocr import PyTessBaseAPI
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser("Enter Image Path")
parser.add_argument('-i' , '--image' , help="Image Path")
args, unknown = parser.parse_known_args()
images = ['b.jpg']
images[0] = args.image
count = 0
count2 = 0
count3 = 0
with PyTessBaseAPI() as api:
    for img in images:
        api.Init(lang = 'eng')
        api.SetImageFile(img)
        # print api.AllWordConfidences()
        arr = list(api.AllWordConfidences())
        sumarr = sum(arr) / float(len(arr))
```

Getting below error :

```
<ipython-input-3-152e90ab44c3> in <module>
     13 count2 = 0
     14 count3 = 0
---> 15 with PyTessBaseAPI() as api:
     16    for img in images:
     17        api.Init(lang = 'eng')

tesserocr.pyx in tesserocr._tesserocr.PyTessBaseAPI.__cinit__()

tesserocr.pyx in tesserocr._tesserocr.PyTessBaseAPI._init_api()

RuntimeError: Failed to init API, possibly an invalid tessdata path: C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\/tessdata/
```

Anyone aware of this issue ?

Comment: At least your path looks very suspicious. there is slashes `/ ` and backslashes `\ ` mixed.

Answer (score 3):

Add an environment variable on your system to point to the tessdata directory

[image]

You can also pass it in to `PyTessBaseAPI` as per the docs:

```
Args:
    path (str): The name of the parent directory of tessdata. Must end in /.
```

Should be:

```
 with PyTessBaseAPI(path='./') as api:
```

this is if you have the trainedata in the same folder as the script, otherwise substitute `'./'` with your path

Comment: Adding the environment variable worked for me. Thanks a lot for your solution :)

Comment: Sure thing, please mark it as the answer if it helped you :)

Comment: Has anyone solved this issue for Linux? I'm getting the same error. I am using the below code.
import tesserocr; 
api = tesserocr.PyTessBaseAPI(lang = 'eng', path='/usr/local/share/tessdata')

Answer (score 0):

For others who still got this issue if you are using another language other than English, you might need to pass `lang` parameter to tessaocr like this

```
with PyTessBaseAPI(path='./',lang='tur') as api:
        api.SetImage(imageI)
        ocr = api.GetUTF8Text()
        confidence = api.AllWordConfidences()
        print(ocr,confidence)
        return ocr
```

Answer (score 0):

For Windows when we are installing tesserocr library, by default it is going in the below path:
default path-C:\Users\sagar\Anaconda_New\envs\Image_to_OCR\share/tessdata*

On executing our code we are getting this error :
RuntimeError: Failed to init API, possibly an invalid tessdata path: C:\Users\sagar\Anaconda_New\envs\Image_to_OCR/tessdata/

Solution to this problem is cut the tessdata folder from the default path mentioned above and paste it in this path: C:\Users\sagar\Anaconda_New\envs\Image_to_OCR.

If you follow this steps your problem will be solved.